# POST data encoded by cp932 using Python Requests

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-requests

I got into trouble when I tried to post data using `requests`.
I need to post data of Japanese characters URL-encoded by cp932 but data is re-encoded by utf-8 in `requests`.

So my question is: is there any way to avoid utf-8 encode, or any way to specify the encoding?

#### How to reproduce

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import urllib.parse
import requests

encoded_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus('あいう', encoding='cp932')
html = requests.post('http://example.com/', data={'data1':encoded_str})
sys.stdout.write(html.request.body + '\n')
```

#### expected result

The string "あいう" is encoded by cp932.

```
data1=%82%A0%82%A2%82%A4
```

#### The result I got

The string "あいう" is encoded by cp932 and re-encoded by utf-8.

```
data1=%2582%25A0%2582%25A2%2582%25A4
```

#### System Information

- Mac OS 10.12.5
- Python 3.6.1
- Requests 2.18.1

Comment: If you provide a dictionary as `data`, it will be encoded: see the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post). Try this: `data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'data1': 'あいう'}, encoding='cp932')` and pass this as the `data` parameter to `requests.post()`.

Comment: Thank you! I read the docs but I missed it...